# Lazy loading with Backbone isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, lazy-loading, zepto

I'm trying to use this [lazy loading plugin](http://luis-almeida.github.io/unveil/) in a backbone app, I adapted the template to work with the plugin and called and the plugin script in but when I update the browser it seems that all the views images are already rendered, so the lazy loading isn't working properly.

Here is the Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9R9zU/55/

I'm using the lazy loading here:

```
app.BookView = Backbone.View.extend ({
  tagName: 'div',
  className: 'book',
  template: _.template( $( '#bookTemplate' ).html()),
  render: function() {
     this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
     this.$el.find("img").unveil();//lazy loading
     return this;
  }
});
```

Comment: Your titles a bit off ;)

Comment: What do you suggest for the title? :)

Comment: It said lady loading earlier

Comment: Oh, I didn't noticed that

Comment: @user2473588 Are you sure it's not working? Here's an update of the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9R9zU/56/) where I'm passing in a negative number to the plugin and you can see it working.

Comment: Thanks, probably it was a problem with my perception when I've made the scroll down. I didn't thought about to pass a negative number to test the plugin